# Different definitions of the Fermat curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

I am using the definition $X^n+Y^n-Z^n=0$, although I know that the apparently similar alternative $X^n+Y^n+Z^n=0$ is in common use. I wonder if the two are isomorphic? I think they are, otherwise people wouldn't use both definitions with such nonchalance. But then a $\pm$ sign can make a huge difference over fields that are not algebraically closed: think of the empty, projective $\mathbb{R}-$variety $X^2+Y^2=0$ versus the non-empty, non-irreducible $X^2-Y^2=0$.

Comment: They’re not isomorphic, except of course when $n$ is odd, and for most people, that is, I think, the interesting case.

Comment: @Lubin Thank you! Do you know if the automorphism groups are isomorphic, then (also for $n$ even)?

Comment: Well, I’m getting over my head here, but it seems to me clear that $X^n+Y^n+Z^n=0$ has the symmetric group $\mathscr S_3$ in its automorphism group, and that this group of order six does not show up among the automorphisms of $X^n+Y^n=Z^n$.

Comment: @Lubin Yes, I have found many sources saying that the isomorphism group of $X^n+Y^n+Z^n=0$ is the semi-direct product of $\mathcal{S}_3$ with $\mathbb{Z}_n^2$ (multiplication by roots of unity), and I agree that $X^n+Y^n-Z^n=0$ should have less permutations, but I wonder if there is anything more. Still, thanks a lot for your comments.